# Angular how to access data attributes in custom component

Tags: angular, angular16

I'm using some custom `<textarea>` component in Angular which has attribute `dx-char-limit` for remaining characters.

`Textarea` will be used in **ModalDialog** and I'm having issue if I type and close modal window and then reopen the character counter will be not reset.

In `updateCharCounter` function I would like to reset `dx-char-counter` attribute but I don't know how to do it.

```html
<textarea #testinput dx-input [(ngModel)]="textInput" id="myTextarea" name="textarea"
[maxlength]="50" [dx-char-limit]="50" placeholder="Insert text..." (input)="updateCharCounter($event)"></textarea>
```

```
  @ViewChild('testinput',{static: true}) testinput!:ElementRef;


 updateCharCounter(event: Event) {
   // this.testinput is undefined
    console.log('char counter ',  this.testinput.nativeElement);
  }
```

Comment: If you need programmatic access to a component, you need to use a ViewChild

Comment: Also ngOnDestroy could be a good place to do local state clean-up

Comment: @BrandonTaylor I updated my post with VIewChild example but it's not working, I'm getting undefined

Comment: @BrandonTaylor how do I reset character counter attribute

Comment: You would assign the property: `this.testinput['dx-char-limit'] = 20` for example. ViewChild access is only available aftter the view has initialized.

Comment: @BrandonTaylor but I'm getting typescript error ```Element implicitly has an  any  type because expression of type  "dx-char-limit"  can't be used to index type  ElementRef<any> Property  dx-char-limit  does not exist on type  ElementRef<any>```

Comment: That's because it's not an instance of `ElementRef`. It's an instance of whatever type of component it is.